# Amazon s3 prices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've read about amazon pricing here. https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/?nc1=h_ls
So I will have a e-commerce shop with 10 000 items.
 I will need Amazon s3  for item's photo storage.

So I will have have around 10 000 photos on amazon s3.
Right now I wonder: 
`PUT, COPY, POST, or LIST Requests  $0.0054 per 1,000 requests`

So if I upload all photos to aws3 manually and I will upload all 10 000 files at one time. Will I be charged like `0.0054 * 10 000 = $54` or the calculations here are a little bit different? 
UPATE:

I don't know why you are downvoting me.
I just wonder if manually putting file to aws3 counts as put request and if I put 10 files there by drag and dropping them from my computer - will it count as one request or many.

Comment: I think you should ask AWS customer service and not StackOverflow; http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @helgeheldre sure) u right) already asked, thanks for clarification!

Comment: You did find out that it's 0.0054 per 1000? So 10.000 requests would be $0.054 not $54.

Comment: ooooooh GOD THANKS @LucHendriks

Comment: I thought it is for 1 request. Now pricing seems reasonable. cool

Comment: If that was for 1 request the pricing would be insane haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you add an object to s3, a single individual object like one file that counts as a single request

So if you drag and drop 100 files it is 100 requests
If runs a loop and individually sends 100 files it is 100 requests

All this activity will be shown in the billing console https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#